# How do you check both the exception's type as well as they type of the nested exception?

Tags: java, exception, instanceof

Suppose I catch an exception that is of type `AppException` but I only want to carry out certain actions on that exception if it has a nested exception of type `StreamException`.

```
if (e instanceof AppException)
{
    // only handle exception if it contains a
    // nested exception of type 'StreamException'
```

How do I check for a nested `StreamException`?

Answer (score 21):

Do: `if (e instanceof AppException and e.getCause() instanceof StreamException)`.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe instead of examining the cause you could try subclassing AppException for specific purposes.

eg.

```
class StreamException extends AppException {}

try {
    throw new StreamException();
} catch (StreamException e) {
   // treat specifically
} catch (AppException e) {
   // treat generically
   // This will not catch StreamException as it has already been handled 
   // by the previous catch statement.
}
```

You can find this pattern else where in java too. One is example [IOException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html). It is the superclass for many different types of IOException, including, but not limited to EOFException, FileNotFoundException, and UnknownHostException.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (e instanceof AppException) {
    boolean causedByStreamException = false;
    Exception currExp = e;
    while (currExp.getCause() != null){
        currExp = currExp.getCause();
        if (currExp instanceof StreamException){
            causedByStreamException = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (causedByStreamException){
       // Write your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it will be more easily to use ExceptionUtils.indexOfType(e, StreamException.class) != -1 of apache commons library.